# changing x10 mini pro keyboard from querty to azerty CM7 pro's ROM

Tags: keyboard, custom-roms, sony-xperia-x10-mini-pro

I've just managed to install CM7 Ron on my Xperia x10 mini pro
but when I type with the physical/slide keyboard I can't seem to change it from querty to azerty
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try 3rd-party keyboard apps that support transliteration of physical keyboards.

I've previously used [AnySoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard), and with the appropriate language pack (e.g. [French](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anysoftkeyboard.languagepack.french) with has the AZERTY layout) it will transliterate physical keyboard as well.

Comment: I found out how to do it, slightly harder than your answer most likely but it corrects the problem rather than suppress it
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=18283445&postcount=21

Comment: @MikeBryant The drawback of doing it "the hard way" is that reverting back to QWERTY layout is just as difficult (and requires a reboot of the phone.)  With alternate keyboard, it's just a matter of picking a different layout in app settings.